# compareTo does not work properly

Tags: java, compareto

I want to sort a input.txt file and save it in output.txt for instance. I use the insertion sort algorithm. Now my problem: the compareTo method seems to work incorrectly (or at least not how I want to to work). It returns integer greater than 1 thus the algorithm does not really especially for negative numbers. I hope you guys can help me with that problem, thanks!

Thats my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

class Isort
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        if(args[0].equals("int"))
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            sort(array, args[1], args[2]);
        }
        else if(args[0].equals("float"))
        {
            ArrayList<Float> array = new ArrayList<Float>();
            sort(array, args[1], args[2]);
        }
        else if(args[0].equals("String"))
        {
            ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
            sort(array, args[1], args[2]);
        }
        else
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(ArrayList<T> array, String input, String output)
    {   
        try
        {
            File file = new File(input);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));       
            reader.mark((int)file.length() + 1); 
            int count = 0;          
            while(reader.readLine() != null)
            {
                count++;
            }
            reader.reset();
            for(int i = 0; i<count; i++)
            {
                array.add((T)(reader.readLine()));
            }
            reader.close();

            int j;
            T temp;
            for(int i = 1; i < array.size(); i++)
            {
                j = i;
                while(j > 0 && array.get(j-1).compareTo(array.get(j)) > 0)
                {
                    temp = array.get(j);
                    array.set(j,array.get(j-1));
                    array.set(j-1,temp);
                    j -= 1;
                    System.out.println(array);
                }
            }
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output);
            for(int i = 0; i<array.size(); i++)
            {
                writer.write(String.valueOf(array.get(i)));
                writer.write(System.getProperty ("line.separator")); 
            }
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What evidence do you have that `compareTo` is not working?  In other words, what is the smallest test case that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I'm pretty certain compareTo works properly for Integer, Float and String. What is the behaviour that you expect when comparing negative numbers?

Comment: input: -10 -1 output: -1 -10 and that obviously wrong

I might try to overwrite compareTo later.

Comment: Not sure, what you are expecting, but `(T)reader.readLine()` does *not* convert a string into a number...

Comment: Do I spot a bubble sort there? What's wrong with `Collections.sort`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are confused by the use of generics. You are making generic `ArrayLists` of `Integer`, `Long` and `String`. You are then reading a line of text and attempting to cast it to `T`.

This will not do anything at runtime due to type-erasure. In all of the cases above (int, long and string) you will be passing an `ArrayList<Object>` and adding `String` to the list. When you read the `String` from the file the cast doesn't do anything except cast it to an `Object` which `String` already is. So unless the `compareTo` of `String` matches your requirements for `int` and `long` this will not work.

In reply to comment...

That's the point. Casting to `T` or really using generics at all in this case don't do what you need. In all cases you are reading and comparing `String`. Instead you need to have three methods `readInt`, `readLong` and `readString` and call the appropriate one based on what you are expecting. One option would be to use an interface of `readNextValue` and pass in an appropriate implementation depending on the situation.

Comment: I cast it to `T` because otherwise I cannout even compile it. I would rather use something like `T.valueOf(reader.readline())` but that is not possible.
And if i would only use int or long the algorithm would not work either. For example: input: -1, -10 output: -1, -10 (instead of -10, -1)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to using a "**Comparator**" class in "**Collections.sort(...)**" method. You can find an example here-> http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/08/04/collections-sort-java/.

Comment: The issue is the improper use of generics, not `compareTo`. The OP believes the cast to `T` will do something.